# An alert like whatsapp when app is in background in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using One Signal push notifications in my ionic app. I want to show an alert when i receive a notification when my app is in background.

I tried using the platform pause and remuse functionality to check for background and foreground and then generate an alert when app was in background using ionic alert controller but was not able to produce the desired result.

I want a pop up dialog box like one in whastapp when u receive a message.

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this.

Comment: have you found something?

Comment: After a lot of digging around I was not able to do do this. One of the limitations of a hybrid mobile app as compared to a native one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve what you're trying to achieve through the use of OneSignal alone. The OneSignal plugin for Ionic has two calls to action:
`handleNotificationReceived()` & `handleNotificationOpened()`

The first one is called when the notification is received and the app is in the foreground.

And the second is called when the app is launched from the notification.

You would need some other service to record when notifications are sent to see if there were any when the app was launched by itself. If you use OneSignal's REST API to send notifications yourself, you can record when a notification is sent, and then when the app is launched by itself, you can fetch missed notifications or notification count from your own server. That's just one way you can do it.

But OneSignal is a push notification service, which send notifications. Even if you did FCM yourself and went through the scenario you mentioned, the results would be the same. 
It's not a OneSignal issue. It's the way notifications are designed.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. What i actually want is to generate a popup like i get in Whatsapp when you get a new message. Which is completely not related to One Signal.